# Fetch sms From phone and upload on server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Here i am fetch sms from phone and upload 10 sms on server all code working fine but instead of 10 sms upload to server only Specific one sms uploaded 10 time to server, pls tell me what i am missing in my code?

here is my message_class.Java code.

```
      public class message_class extends Activity{
int j = 0;
Button btninbox;

ListView lstView;

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

ArrayList<Message_Item> msg_list;

String Str_Msg, Str_Phone,dated;

Msg_adapter msg_adapter;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.msginbox_layout);

    msg_list = new ArrayList<Message_Item>();
    btninbox = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_inbox);
    btninbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent intent = new Intent(message_class.this, Msg_Recive.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });



    lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_msg);

    fetchInbox();




            final int arraysize = msg_list.size();


            for (int j=0; j<10;j++){

                Str_Msg = msg_list.get(j).getStrMsg().toString();
                Str_Phone = msg_list.get(j).getStrNumber().toString();
                Toast.makeText(message_class.this, Str_Phone+" "+Str_Msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            new HttpAsyncTask()
                    .execute("http://demo.glowsosl.com/synchs_dsda_app/insert_details_msg.php");



            msg_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }



}



private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        Contacts person = new Contacts();
        person.setPhone(Str_Phone);
        person.setName(Str_Msg);


        return POST(urls[0], person);



    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result + "Data Sent!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}

public static String POST(String url, Contacts person) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.accumulate("contact_no", person.getPhone());
        jsonObject.accumulate("sim_num", "Unknown");
        jsonObject.accumulate("msg", person.getName());

        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();



        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the
        // content
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    return result + "," + person.getName() + ","
            + person.getPhone();
}

ArrayList<String> jsonStringToArray(String jsonString) throws JSONException {

    ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        stringArray.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
    }

    return stringArray;

}

public void fetchInbox() {
    // ArrayList sms = new ArrayList();

    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms,
            new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body" }, null, null,
            null);
     //for (int i =0; i<((JSONArray) cursor).length();i++){
         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     //}
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String address = cursor.getString(1);
        String date = cursor.getString(2);
        String body = cursor.getString(3);

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cursor.getString(2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        msg_list.add(new Message_Item(address, body,date));

    }

    msg_adapter = new Msg_adapter(msg_list, message_class.this);
    lstView.setAdapter(msg_adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying for loop out side async task use it in doInBackground method.

Your doInBackground method will look like follows.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String result="";
    for(int i = 0; i < msg_list.size(); i++){
       Str_Msg = msg_list.get(i).getStrMsg().toString();
       Str_Phone = msg_list.get(i).getStrNumber().toString();

       Contacts person = new Contacts();
       person.setPhone(Str_Phone);
       person.setName(Str_Msg);
       result= result + POST(urls[0], person);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And call this async task only once.

Enjoy!!